# How to obtain strings.xml files for different languages from an apk file (Android 8)

Tags: android, multilingual, apktool

I’m using apktool (and other tools) with an android apk file, to try to find the strings.xml files used for different languages (inside values-** directories). However, I can’t find any languages directories (e.g. values-fr), and I know the app supports different languages. I’m using a phone with Android 8. When I use a phone with Android 4, I do find the values-** directories.

Comment: May be your apk is created from app bundle and because of that doesn't include other language resources.

Comment: @Vivart Thanks; I think it could be possible that app bundle was used to create the app, and dynamic updating of strings is used.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I get strings from apk via Android studio: `Build -> Analyze APK -> select APK -> click on resources.arsc -> string`. From table with strings you can copy to excel.

[image]

Comment: @ Evstropov V Thanks a lot for this cool trick; is there an easy way to create the final strings.xml files? Or do we have to manually type string by string for each language file <string name=“my_string_1”>my_text_1</string>

Comment: I got resources.pb from an aab but AS seems unable to open it